# c# video equivalent to image.fromstream? Or changing the scope of the following script to allow video too

Tags: c#, php

The following is a part of an upload class in a c# script. I'm a php programmer, I've never messed with c# much but I'm trying to learn. This upload script will not handle anything except images, I need to adapt this class to handle other types of media also, or rewrite it all together. If I'm correct, I realize that

```
using (Image image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
```

basically says that the scope of the following is Image, only an image can be used or the object is discarded? And also that the variable image is being created from an Image from the file stream, which I understand to be, like... the $_FILES array in php?

I dunno, I don't really care about making thumbnails right now either way, so if this can be taken out and still process the upload I'm totally cool with that, I just haven't had any luck getting this thing to take anything but images, even when commenting out that whole part of the class...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dir = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "files");

        if (Request.Files.Count == 0)
        {
            // No files were posted
            Response.StatusCode = 500;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                // Only one file at a time is posted
                HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[0];

                // Size limit 100MB
                if (file.ContentLength > 102400000)
                {
                    // File too large
                    Response.StatusCode = 500;
                }
                else
                {
                    string id = Request.QueryString["userId"];
                    string[] folders = userDir(id);

                    foreach (string folder in folders)
                    {
                        dir = Path.Combine(dir, folder);
                        if (!Directory.Exists(dir)) Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
                    }
                    string path = Path.Combine(dir, String.Concat(Request.QueryString["batchId"], "_", file.FileName));
                    file.SaveAs(path);

                    // Create thumbnail
                    int dot = path.LastIndexOf('.');
                    string thumbpath = String.Concat(path.Substring(0, dot), "_thumb", path.Substring(dot));
                    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(file.InputStream))
                    {
                        // Find the ratio that will create maximum height or width of 100px.
                        double ratio = Math.Max(image.Width / 100.0, image.Height / 100.0);

                        using (Image thumb = new Bitmap(image, new Size((int)Math.Round(image.Width / ratio), (int)Math.Round(image.Height / ratio))))
                        {
                            using (Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
                            {
                                // Make sure thumbnail is not crappy
                                graphic.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                                graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
                                graphic.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                                // JPEG
                                ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()[1];

                                // 90% quality
                                EncoderParameters encode = new EncoderParameters(1);
                                encode.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90L);

                                // Resize
                                graphic.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, thumb.Width, thumb.Height));

                                // Save
                                thumb.Save(thumbpath, codec, encode);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    // Success
                    Response.StatusCode = 200;
                }

            }
            catch
            {
                // Something went wrong
                Response.StatusCode = 500;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I am not quite sure if you are wanting to simply save the file to the server or what.  I'm not clear on the goal.  However, if you are simply wanting to save the file to the server, it appears you have already done that with "file.SaveAs(path);".  If that is the goal, just rip out the other stuff and your set.  If you need more fine grain control of the file you can use the below code, using a different constructor as needed.

```
byte[] buffer;
int bytesRead = 0;
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream("myfile.whatever"); // not sure about your constructor, look this one up
while((bytesRead = file.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
  fs.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
fs.Close();
```

Now I did not actually try this, but it should give you a good base from which you can start.

Comment: if you are simply wanting to save the file to the server, it appears you have already done that with "file.SaveAs(path);". If that is the goal, just rip out the other stuff and your set.

That's totally what I thought too, but it doesn't seem to accept anything not an image, so I'm guessing my problem lies elsewhere.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> basically says that the scope of the
>   following is Image, only an image can
>   be used or the object is discarded?

1. Scope has a bit different meaning in C#. Scope, in simple words, refers to the region of code where a particular variable can be used.
2. Using statement takes care of disposing the objects as soon as it's execution completes. This means that the Image object you have created in the using block, will be disposed off from the memory as soon as the execution of that using block is over.
3. If the stream you are using is not from a valid image file, that line of code will throw ArgumentException.

If you want create thumbnails for a video file, you can make use of IMediaDet interface. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/ExtractVideoFrames.aspx) is an article that explains about creating thumbnails from a video file.